# Overriding symfony radio widget

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

Default radio widget creates a following structure:

```
<label>...</label>
<div id="...">
<div class="clearfix prettyradio labelright  blue">
<input type="radio" id="..._0" name="..." value="..." style="display: none;">
<a href="#" class=""></a>
...
</div>
```

I found the radio_widget block, but it contains only an input itself. So I can customize there only this part:

```
<input type="radio" id="..._0" name="..." value="1" style="display: none;">
```

But I can't understand how to change whole the structure of radio choice field?

Also, does anybody knows, why symfony adds display:none to the input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you're using [Radio Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/radio.html), you can customize only the `input` part of the `radio_widget` block by calling `form_widget(form.yourField)`, all it displays is,

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

But if you're using [Choice Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/choice.html) to display Radio Fields `(expanded => true and multiple => false)`.  You'll then have to override the `choice_widget` block, which call for each child element the `radio_widget` block surrounded by a global `div`

How did you get the "display:none"? because there's no style such this in the default block.

Comment: Thanks. What about "dysplay:none" - there is no such part in source code, it appears only in firebug. So everything is fine now!

Comment: And also, can I customize widjet block ONLY for one specific field? For example, I want some radio buttons appear with a customized structure, and other with the default.

Comment: I can customize a form row, like: `_prefix_fieldname_row`, but what about that choice field structure?

Comment: Yes, you can also customize specific fields according to fieldname. Choice field do not matter here, because it calls specific type fields according to it's behavior (expanded, multiple). So, here to customize specific fields you should use something like _prefix_fieldname_widget.

Comment: You can also override widget blocks at [different levels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) of your application.

Comment: I actually couldn't understand what exactly would be a name of the block which I need to override? For example let's take my radio filed. What should I put in `_prefix_fieldname_widget` instead of 'widget' to override it?

Comment: I actually couldn't understand what exactly would be a name of the block which I need to override? For example let's take my radio filed. What should I put in `_prefix_fieldname_widget` instead of 'widget' to override it?

Comment: Here for this specific case, you should use something like _field_name_widget where field_name represents the id attribute of the widget you want to override. ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field))

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to override the way an individual radio field is rendered - i.e. how each input field in the group is rendered - use this formula for the block name:

```
_<form name>_<field name>_entry_widget
```

Note this bit: `_entry`

If you're using an expanded choice field `..._entry_row` and `..._entry_label` won't work because they aren't used for the individual choices - well for radio buttons at least.

More generally you can find out a lot about which block Symfony intends to use during the next call to `{{ form_widget(form) }}` function call using this code:

```
{% for b in form.vars.block_prefixes %}
    {{ dump(b) }}
{% endfor %}
```

or you might want to look at `child` in some situations:

```
{% for b in child.vars.block_prefixes %}
    {{ dump(b) }}
{% endfor %}
```